# Ember.run.debounce with immediate argument does not work as expected

Tags: ember.js, debouncing

If you call [`Ember.run.debounce`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_debounce) with `immediate` argument set to true, it works **only if** `Ember.run.debounce` was not called ever before (at least with the same context and function argument). And by 'it works' I mean 'it fires the passed function'.

This is the [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/2125/edit?html,js,output) demonstrating this behavior.

Click on div **once**, wait 1 second and alert fires as expected. But successive clicks do nothing. It only fires for the first time. If you click multiple times in 1 second period it doesn't show alert window whatsoever, because `debounce` was called multiple times. If you don't use the `immediate` parameter at all, everything works as expected.

Is this really a correct behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is switching from not immediate to immediate isn't the programmed scenario.  Or you could say the functionality isn't built to handle switching.

The immediate workflow is to run the code right away, and block any instance of the code from running until the timeout has expired.  So when you pass in a non-immediate and then quickly send in another immediate, it removes the non-immediate from the queue (assuming it's already run) and then just blocks for an additional 1000 ms (per the immediate workflow).

You can pretty easily work around this by just changing your time based on immediate.

```
var timeout = this.immediate?1:10000;
Ember.run.debounce(this, this.alertMe, timeout);

// Run immediately for further clicks
this.immediate = true;
```

Followup, this is fixed in the latest canary build.

http://jsbin.com/ucanam/2511/edit

Comment: I'm working up a PR for this, it seems like a simple enough use case to handle.